# How can I add controls into Borderpane in Javafx?

Tags: javafx, borderpane

I'm very new to Javafx and I'm facing a problem right now.
I want to add controls into a borderpane. So I did this:

```
borderPane.setLeft(label1);
```

And when I try placing another label beside `label1`, I did this:

```
borderPane.setLeft(label2);
```

But it replaces `label1`. I want them to be side by side. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add two controls in a single space of [`BorderPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html). If you need to add multiple controls you need to use a Container, such as a [HBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html).

- HBox places the children in horizontal order
- VBox places the children in vertical order

Add both labels to it, and then add the HBox to the left side of the BorderPane.

```
HBox box = new HBox();
box.getChildren.addAll(label1, label2);
borderPane.setLeft(box);
```

Comment: Imo for more detailed placement i like GridPane more :)

Comment: That is a personal choice and moreover depends on what you are trying to achieve.